# Intuition and name for $a^T R a$

Tags: linear-algebra

I have seen this operation before but cant seem to recall the name or corresponding theory. This operation changes inner product $<a,b> = a^T b$ to $a^T R b$, where $R$ is some matrix. What does this do intuitively and what is the name?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The expression  $x^TRy$ is a [bilinear form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bilinear_form) and for $R$ positive definite symmetric represents an inner product.

Comment: Isn't $a^T R a$ called something like quadratic form?

Comment: yes when $R$ is symmetric, not necessarily positive definite, for x=y we talk of quadratic form

Comment: I think the symmetry is also unnecessary, just makes your life much easier.

Comment: Yes of course it is well defined for any matrix but usually we refer to the unique symmetric part to study its properties.

Comment: @Botond I didn’t mention that because it seems thst the OP was referring to inner products but that’s a good point of course! Bye

Answer (score 2):

If $R$ is symmetric and positive definite, then the operation you are referring to is simply a change of basis on the underlying space. Such a change results in the entries of the column matrices representing the vectors $a$ and $b$ changing. We want to keep the inner product unchanged (as the inner product shouldn't depend on what coordinates we impose on the space), so we correct it by inserting $R$. We actually have $R=A^TA$ where $A$ is the change of basis matrix in the appropriate direction.